# In Basic SML I cant seem to fix this mismatch type error

Tags: sml

```
structure Random =   (* Define a module named Random *)
  struct
    val rand = Random.rand  (* Expose the rand function from the Random library *)
  end;

fun generateRandomArray() =
  let
    val randVector = Array.array(100, 0)  (* Create a new array of length 100, initialized to 0s *)
    val _ = Array.tabulate (100, fn i =>  Array.update(randVector, i, Random.randRange(1, 100) (Random.rand())))   (* Generate a random integer between 1 and 100 (inclusive) for each element in the array *)
  in
    randVector
  end;

(* O(n) *)
fun average (vector : int array) =
  let
    val sum = foldl (op +) 0 vector   (* Compute the sum of all elements in the array *)
    val n = Array.length vector   (* Get the length of the array *)
  in
    sum div n   (* Compute and return the integer division of the sum and the length *)
  end;

(* O(nlogn) *)
fun median (vector : int array) =
  let
    val sorted = Array.toList vector |> ListMergeSort.sort (op <)   (* Convert the array to a list, sort the list, and convert it back to an array *)
    val n = length sorted
    val mid = n div 2
  in
    if n mod 2 = 0 then (List.nth (sorted, mid - 1) + List.nth (sorted, mid)) div 2   (* Compute the average of the middle two elements if the length is even *)
    else List.nth (sorted, mid)   (* Otherwise, return the middle element *)
  end;

(* O(n) *)
fun midrange (vector : int array) =
  let
    val max = Array.foldl Int.max ~0 vector   (* Get the maximum value in the array *)
    val min = Array.foldl Int.min 100 vector   (* Get the minimum value in the array *)
  in
    (max + min) div 2   (* Compute and return the integer division of the sum of the max and min values and 2 *)
  end;

(* O(n) *)
fun standardDeviation (vector : int array) =
  let
    val avg = real (average vector)
    val squaredDiff = Array.tabulate (Array.length vector, fn i => Real.pow(Real.fromInt(Array.sub(vector, i) - average vector), 2))   (* Compute the squared difference of each element and the mean *)
    val variance = (List.foldr (op +) 0 squaredDiff) / real(Array.length vector)   (* Compute the variance by summing the squared differences and dividing by the length *)
  in
    Real.sqrt(variance)   (* Compute and return the square root of the variance \*)
  end;

val randVector = generateRandomArray();   (* Generate a random array of length 100 *)

print("Random Vector: " ^ Array.toString randVector ^ "\n");   (* Print the random array *)
print("Average: " ^ Int.toString (average randVector) ^ "\n");   (* Print the average of the array *)
print("Median: " ^ Int.toString (median randVector) ^ "\n");   (* Print the median of the array *)
print("Midrange: " ^ Int.toString (midrange randVector) ^ "\n");   (* Print the midrange of the array *)
print("Standard Deviation: " ^ Real.toString (standardDeviation randVector) ^ "\n");   (* Print the standard deviation*)
```

This program should generates a random array of 100 integers ranging from 1 to 100 (inclusive), then calculates various statistical measures on the array including its average, median, midrange, and standard deviation.

The program starts by defining a module named Random which exposes the rand function from the Random library. It then defines a function named generateRandomArray that creates a new array of length 100, initialized to 0s, and fills it with random integers generated using the rand function from the Random library.

The program then defines four functions to calculate various statistical measures on the array. The average function calculates the average of the array by summing all of the elements and dividing by the length. The median function calculates the median of the array by sorting it and returning either the middle element or the average of the two middle elements, depending on the length of the array. The midrange function calculates the midrange of the array by finding the minimum and maximum values and taking their average. The standardDeviation function calculates the standard deviation of the array by first computing the variance, which is the average of the squared differences between each element and the mean, and then taking the square root of the variance.

Finally, the program generates a random array using the generateRandomArray function, and prints out the array as well as its average, median, midrange, and standard deviation.

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Mon Oct  3 21:03:45 2022]
[opening lab5-1.sml]
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
structure Random : sig val rand : int * int -> ?.Random.rand end
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
lab5-1.sml:9.74-9.90 Error: unbound variable or constructor: randRange in path Random.randRange
lab5-1.sml:9.100-9.113 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int * int
  operand:         unit
  in expression:
    Random.rand ()
/usr/lib/smlnj/bin/sml: Fatal error -- Uncaught exception Error with 0
 raised at ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
```

I cant seem to fix the mismatch error. Any help would thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've shadowed the standard `Random` structure by creating your own `Random` structure, so `Random.randRange` does not exist for the remainder of your program.

If this is really what you want to do you can rename the standard `Random` structure with something like:

```
structure R = Random

structure Random =
  struct
    ...
  end
```

But if you overcome the errors that creates your `average` function is attempting to use `foldl` on an `int array`, but `foldl` works on *lists*. You likely meant to use `Array.foldl`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at the documentation for the Random structure:

https://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Util/str-Random.html

I see some immediate problems:

- the type of "rand" is
  val rand : (int * int) -> rand

For starters, your call to Random.rand is incorrect, because you don't declare the seed parameters.

```
- val generated_rand_with_seeds = Random.rand(2,133);
val generated_rand_with_seeds =
  RND
    {borrow=ref false,congx=ref 0wx15AC1D0F,index=ref 0,
     vals=[|0wx9476E5C,0wxD382FA2,0wx3018AA4,0wx35B5FD1F,0wx53735D04,
           0wx2FC7B9E5,0wx28897E27,0wx2F749CDB,0wx4190F387,0wx70A72BD7,
           0wx31590BE,0wx55963724,0wx72D8AA2E,0wx2260F134,0wx179202ED,
           0wx57248201,...|]} : Random.rand
```

And "rand.Range" has this type:
val randRange : (int * int) -> rand -> int

but you called it like so

```
Random.randRange(1, 100) (Random.rand())
```

which did a function application when it was in fact curried, so you should've called it like this:

```
- val random_number_with_generated_rand = Random.randRange(1,100) generated_rand_with_seeds;
val random_number_with_generated_rand = 15 : int
```